# schedule Jenkins to build at specified time

Tags: jenkins, triggers, hudson

I want to configure JSON build to work at 31st of Marc at 01:00 AM. I configued it
like "0 1 31 3 5". But it does not show me advices as my last build will beon that etc etc. That's why I thought I am makinga big problem because normally it shows me advices.

Could you please tell me if 0 1 31 3 5 is ok for tomorrow(31st March) or there is a problem at scheduling ?

Regards
Alper

Comment: why there is 5 for dow. just try 0 1 31 3 *. This should do because it anyway defines your required time.

Comment: 5 is 5th of the week.

Comment: yeah, I know that. I thought you wanted to run it every year on 31st march. Anyways it should be good unless jenkins have some other bug, like using double digits as 00 01 31 03 05. I had such an issue few year back in some other cron implementations, so just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah Seems like there is an issue with march 31st, my solution was to skip the day since my problem was to only schedule it on 31st March. like 00 24 * 03 *